# Azure data factory - Continue on conflict on insert

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, data-migration, azure-data-factory

We are building data migration pipeline using Azure data factory (ADF). We are transferring data from one CosmosDb instance to another. We plan to enable dual writes, so that we write to both the databases before migration begins to ensure that during migration if any data point changes both the databases get the most updated data. However, In ADF there is only Insert or upsert options available. Our case is on Insert if it gets 'conflict' continue and fail the pipeline. Can anyone give any pointers on how to achieve that in ADF?
Other option would be to create our own custom tool using CosmosDb libraries to transfer data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing a live migration ADF is not the right tool to use as this is intended for offline migrations. If you are migrating from one Cosmos DB account to another your best option is to use the [Cosmos DB Live Data Migrator](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cosmosdb-live-data-migrator).

This tool also provides dead letter support as well which is another requirement you have.

Comment: Thanks Marks for your answer. I will look into Cosmos DB Live Data migrator.  Is there a way in this tool where I can mention to not update the destination if document already exists at destination? I want to safeguard for situation where data in source db is changed after it is read but before written to the destination? Before migration, I  will start writing to both source and destination dbs. So for the case I mentioned, the destination DB will already have the updated document and I do not want to overwrite it with source's stale data.

Comment: This isn't a bi-directional tool. It's uni-directional so this scenario is not possible. You only write into your source container and then can do reads from the destination to test. Once you're happy with the results, you cut over the connection string in your SDK client.